# On Linux, what's a good way to to use HID reports over USB?

Tags: linux, usb, hid, iokit

On macOS, I use IOKit to get and set HID reports over a USB connection (for the curious, this is a controller for a standing desk that allows you to raise and lower the desk programmatically). I can get a list of devices using an `IOHIDManager`:

```objc
_manager = IOHIDManagerCreate(NULL, 0);

NSDictionary *deviceQuery = @{@kIOHIDVendorIDKey: @0x12D3, @kIOHIDProductIDKey: @0x0002};
IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatching(_manager, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)deviceQuery);
IOHIDManagerOpen(_manager, kIOHIDManagerOptionNone);

CFSetRef devices = IOHIDManagerCopyDevices(_manager);

// pick a device from the set and you eventually get a...
IOHIDDeviceRef myDevice = foo;
```

I then build up request buffers and make requests using:

```objc
int8_t *_buffer = ...;
IOHIDDeviceSetReport(myDevice, kIOHIDReportTypeFeature, *_buffer & 0xff, (const uint8_t *)_buffer, REQ_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

… and read responses using:

```objc
IOHIDDeviceGetReport(myDevice, kIOHIDReportTypeFeature, *_buffer & 0xff, (uint8_t *)_buffer, RES_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

What is an analogous way to do this on Linux? I've never worked with USB on Linux before (nor HID devices), and I'm open to pretty much any stack as long as it'll run on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

to list all devices, capturing interfaces,... on linux *libsub* is used, see this http://www.microchip.com/forums/m340898.aspx

for the HID reports you can use `usbhid-dump` http://www.pkill.info/linux/man/8-usbhid-dump/ https://github.com/DIGImend/usbhid-dump or *hidraw* for low-level